# MVEL not evaluating and throwing invalid number literal

Tags: java, mvel

MVEL is not evaluating the expression properly  which contains the string with number like below

```
<div><br>@{11412Test}</div>
```

*Caused by: [Error: invalid number literal: 11412Test]
[Near : {... v>
@{11412Test} ....}]*

*[Line: 1, Column: 57]
at org.mvel2.util.ParseTools.isNumber(ParseTools.java:1903)
at org.mvel2.ast.ASTNode.setName(ASTNode.java:257)
at org.mvel2.ast.ASTNode.(ASTNode.java:422)
at org.mvel2.compiler.AbstractParser.createPropertyToken(AbstractParser.java:1428)
at org.mvel2.compiler.AbstractParser.nextToken(AbstractParser.java:896)
at org.mvel2.compiler.ExpressionCompiler._compile(ExpressionCompiler.java:127)
at org.mvel2.MVEL.compileExpression(MVEL.java:832)
at org.mvel2.templates.res.CompiledExpressionNode.(CompiledExpressionNode.java:41)
at org.mvel2.templates.TemplateCompiler.compileFrom(TemplateCompiler.java:211)
... 131 more*

and i am using mvel2-2.4.14-Final version.
Please let me know how to resolve this issue.
Note: If it is only string'Test' or only number '11412' then it is working

Comment: So what is it you actually want to achieve? The whole string is not a number, so it can't be parsed as one. And from your comment on the answer, it looks like you don't just want a String either.

Comment: hi @Jorn, i want to evaluate this expression and replace with the actual value.
<div><br>@{11412Test}</div> will get replace with <div><br>Hi,some content from hmap</div> and Hi,some content from hmap is the actual value of @{11412Test}.
which should get replace with the content.

Comment: *"Please provide a proper solution"* The proper solution is to not use names that start with a digit.

Answer (score 0):

The claim that "it is working with number '11412'" is not true:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.mvel2.templates.TemplateRuntime;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String template = "Hello, @{11412}";
        HashMap<String,Object> vars = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        vars.put("11412", "world");
        System.out.println(TemplateRuntime.eval(template, vars));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, 11412
```

`@{11412}` was *not* replaced by `world`. `11412` was just interpreted as a literal integer (not as a variable name).

Like in most (if not all) languages, names are not allowed to start with a digit. A token that starts with
a digit is interpreted as a number. You may, however, start with an underscore:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.mvel2.templates.TemplateRuntime;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String template = "Hello, @{_11412}";
        HashMap<String,Object> vars = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        vars.put("_11412", "world");
        System.out.println(TemplateRuntime.eval(template, vars));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, world
```

`_11412Test` will work as well.

Comment: I already tried this option but did not work out. How would this string will get replace in actual template. This is not working

Comment: @moh Now that I understand your question, I rewrote my answer.